# iphone Get current year as string

Tags: objective-c

How do I get current year as string in Obj-C ?

Also how do I compare the same using another year value ?

Is it advisable to do a string comparision OR dirctly year-to-year comparision ?

Answer (score 121):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
NSString *yearString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

// Swift
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
let year = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

You can compare `NSString`s via the `-isEqualToString:` method.

Comment: Does stringFromDate work fine? I think it says might not respond to selector. Is there any other way?

Comment: It definitely does work fine. `-stringFromDate:` is an `NSDateFormatter` method: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/stringFromDate:

Comment: The date format should be @"yyyy" (lowercase).  The uppercase gives the year of the week the date is in.  So for January 1, 2011, @"YYYY" returns 2010.

Answer (score 38):

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSInteger year = [gregorian component:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:NSDate.date];
```

Note: there are several calendar identifiers besides NSGregorianCalendar.  Use whatever is appropriate for your locale.  You can ask for whatever set of components you'd like by bitwise OR'ing the fields together (e.g., NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit) and using `components:fromDate` instead.  You can read about it in the [Date and Time Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html).

With calendar components as primitive types, comparisons are efficient.

Comment: the first line needs `autorelease`

Comment: @DTs I believe we can all assume ARC by now.

Comment: @DavidH - would that it be true; but some code is more legacy than others.  OTOH, I think that first line is an autoreleased convenience method anyway.

Comment: I prefer your answer; date formatter is costly to alloc-init each time

Comment: NOTE! calendarWithIdentifier: is iOS 8 only, and so is component:fromDate:

Comment: iOS7 will break it down.

Answer (score 3):

In **Swift** you can get only year by given code

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
let dateStr = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
print(dateStr)
```

**Output:**

2017

Answer (score 2):

you can get by following code in objective c

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
int year = [components year];
NSString *strFromyear = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",year];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

Easier way to get any elements of date as an optional String.

```
extension Date {

  // Year 
  var currentYear: String? {
    return getDateComponent(dateFormat: "yy")
    //return getDateComponent(dateFormat: "yyyy")
  }


  func getDateComponent(dateFormat: String) -> String? {
    let format = DateFormatter()
    format.dateFormat = dateFormat
    return format.string(from: self)
  }


}


print("-- \(Date().currentYear)")  // result -- Optional("2017")
```