# "setDateFormat" does not work with GMT?

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

i'm wondering why my setDateFormat does not work when i use it with a different timezone , here GMT :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"]; //this doesn't work, nothing appears
//[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle]; //this works
```

but if i use the default timeZone, it works :

```
NSDateFormatter *Dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[Dateformat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"]; //this works
```

Thanks for your help

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to NSLog a string by using this dateFormatter, its woking for me..when i make a string as-

```
NSString *dateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"%@",dateStr);
```

and its give me this -

```
09-08-2011
```

Comment: thanks, yeah i have tested it with a nslog, but it's more about the "setDateFormat" : in my example : the second chunk of code works fine, it's the timeZone by default, but if i use a different time zone like "GMT" : the setDateFormat doesn't work : the NSLog doesn't show the date format...

Comment: edit : oops sorry i made a mistake, actually i put another format afterwards in the code, i didn't see that i changed the format twice. Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Additionaly, you should probably be using: [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"] instead of [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"].
Using YYYY is a common mistake according to the apple documentation. It returns the year number of the year the week is in (according to ISO week numbering scheme). This can be off one year. Lowercase yyyy is normally the correct version.
See: [iphone Get current year as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689609/iphone-get-current-year-as-string)
(The comment of Anna Karenina)